# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>' (Django)

Tags: python, django

I ran into this error after executing `python manage.py runserver`. This was just after pulling the repository after not having worked on it in a while. I tried checking to see that I had the dependencies installed and that my virtual environment was active and I still get the error.

The last line of the error (also the title of the question) is

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I am new to Django so I have no idea what the cause of this error is.

Comment: You'd better provide text descriptions for errors. Console deals fine with <ctrl+c>.

Comment: Please provide your traceback as a text instead of a screenshot. Please also provide related source code.

Answer (score 71):

I had the same issue here. After having suffering for a few hours stuck, I figured out the reason. It's very basic. 
We forgot to run the migrate commands.
To fix, run the below commands in order:

```
python manage.py migrate

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

While the error notification is not relavance but this fix the error anyway :v.

You can read further information about migration [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/).

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well.

Comment: Solved for me too! Thank you! Was stuck for hours!

Answer (score 27):

The same issue is also occurred when someone misspell filename, directory name or app name... for example when someone create an app by the name of users and then he/she want to enlist the app in the INSTALLED_APPS List available in the setting.py file in misspell way like ............ users.app.UsersConfig instead of users.apps.UsersConfig

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I added a new app that kicked my server over, couldn't find the problem until It saw this. I had misspelled the app name in settings.py. Problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks! that was my case. I mispelled one of my custom apps'name in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: This solved my problem. But did you know the reason? What is the relation?

Answer (score 10):

if you have virtualenv managing your packages make sure that is activated it before you run your app.

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks! forgot the very basic step

Answer (score 1):

I am sensing that you are trying to import bootstrap files for your website.This can be conveniently done by adding the hyperlink from the bootstrap cdn on your base template.
Also you can download the boostrap package and copy the css and js files under the static folder in your project.

Comment: I don't think that's it actually. I just hit the same problem (which is how I found this question) and I haven't done anything with templates yet - still setting up models, so no bootstrap on my part.

Answer (score 1):

first but not always, it seems you have deleted a file/folder from your project. if so, remember to delete the path that was serving that folder "path in the project urls.py"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing the `\` when using multiple lines to import:

```
from .models import Country, State, Locality, Address,\
PercentageAmount, Condominium, Condominium_expenses_report,\
    FunctionalUnit, Percentage, FunctionalUnit_expenses_report,\
        Expense, Bill, Judgment, Insurance, Concept
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I also do not have any bootstrap included in my application. In my case the  virtualenv server stopped running. Just reboot the Django server and you are good to go again.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake and to solve the issue try this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```