# How to make virtualenv Django server work? // 'missing attribute' according to command prompt

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

after wasting saturdays eve googling for a solution to finally make a Django server work, i need your assistance..

I first of all want to set up my project in that way that http://127.0.0.1:8000/ redirects me to the index.html site. But somehow I am not able to run the Django server within my virtualenv (access denied).

I handled error over error in the past few hours (inserted a Secret key, inserted silenced_system_checks since E408/09/10 occured as errors before the current error) and here I stuck now. I am not capable to understand the prompt error at all. I assume that Django wants to start the server but can't find a file/html to return?

**urls.py** // dassocc_app dir

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/dasocc_site/dasocc_app/templates/', include("dasocc_app.views")),
    path('', views.liga, name="index"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render


def liga(request):
    liga = ['1. Bundesliga', 'Premier League', 'La liga']
    return render(request, 'dasocc_app/templates/index.html', {'liga': liga})
```

**urls.py** // dasocc_site dir

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from dassoc_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.liga, name='index')
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBWod.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us your `views.py`? Most importantly `views.index()`

Comment: @pissall added - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your troublemaker is the line `path('', views.index, name="index")`. It cannot find a function called `index` in your `views.py`.

Assuming the function you want to call is `liga()` you will have to write

`path('', views.liga, name="index")`.

Or you could rename your `liga` function to `index`

## #2

Kindly change your `dassoc_site.urls`:

**dassoc_site/urls.py**

```py
from dasocc_app import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^$', views.liga, name='index'),
               url(r'^dassoc-app/', include('dassoc_app.urls')),
              ]
```

**dassoc-app/urls.py**

```py
from django.conf.urls import url

from dasocc_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    # Where home is some random view from your dassocc-app
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed the path function accordingly. The command prompt returned `maximum recursion depth`. I solved this by removing `path('dasocc_app', include("dasocc_site.urls")),` url_pattern. But now the command prompt tells me that it doesn't appear to have any patterns in it.

Comment: At what URL do you want your index page to be show? If `dasocc_app` is your main directory, `path('', views.liga, name="index")` should be in it's `urls.py`

Comment: I want it to be the landing page. The mentioned path function right now is in the `urls.py` file which itself is in the `dasocc_app` dir.

Comment: embedded the output as picture to initial post. `No module named dasocc_app` is the response to the views.py import.

Comment: I did run `django-admin` startproject dassoc_site and then `django-admin startapp dassoc_app` (followed the mozilla dev tutorial). I then included my already prepared files into static (css, js) and the index.html into templates dir.

Comment: dasocc* spelling mistake. 
Updated in answer

Comment: getting closer! Prompt now returns WinError123 in importlib_bootstrap? picture attached

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166319/python-django-error-oserror-winerror-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-vol

Comment: Up and running, thank you so much and lovely hugs to India.

Comment: Thank you. Please upvote if it helped :) Connect with me anytime

Comment: Done!. How to connect? Maybe you could check out my new question/thread, would love to receive some expert opinion :)

Comment: thats the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154408/how-to-concept-a-web-application-dashboard-made-of-django-in-terms-of-backend