# Django local runserver error (won't start)

Tags: python, django

new into this. Can't run localserver from python manage.py runserver. give below error

```
(venv) C:\Users\DeeDee\Desktop\dtre_project\btre>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\DeeDee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "C:\Users\DeeDee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DeeDee\Desktop\dtre_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
..bla bla bla. and last line
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Comment: are you sure your django installation not corrupted? try reinstall django

Comment: it was working perfectly fine a day before. But i'll reinstall django again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python django error OSError: \[WinError 123\] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166319/python-django-error-oserror-winerror-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-vol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Python Script's folder to your System PATH Variable and then install Django again by `py -m pip install Django`

For example, my scripts path is: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts`
because I installed python through Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Neelansh Mathur. But i found that problem lies within my code. some comma and linkage to modules were missing. which i solved and now it's working perfectly. Thank you all for the support. I love this coding than my accounting job. :)