# OS Error: [WinError 123] when installed django in my python project

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2tAL.png)

i had build a simple blog project using Django. When i exit from my virtual env and again tried to run the project after activating virtual env ---- first issue i was facing that django not installed .... after that i run the command inside my project folder ablog "pip install django" and run the project i got this error...

Previuosly also faced this error with one of my project python django...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: \[WinError 123\] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap>' (Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166319/oserror-winerror-123-the-filename-directory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the interpreter wrongly, can be a reason for that